# How to call an activity in Application Class and waiting until it finishes

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to inject an activity before the main activiy shows up. I added the following code in OnCreate method in the application class

```
  [Application]
    public class XYZ: Application
   {
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
     {
             base.OnCreate(bundle);
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SplashActivity));
           intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
           // rest code.. but I dont want it is excuded until my splashactivity 
          closed
      }
   }
```

I cannot find startActivityForResult method in the application class so after StartActivity, the code still is executed that I do not want.
How can make it stop there and wait until splashscreen is closed.

I am not inderested in doing Splasscreen as a mainlauncher. I just want to inject it with another reasons and there is no another way for me.

Note: its for xamarin but java code is also fine.

Comment: I would suggest you just return after starting the activity (not doing any other code) and in your SplashActivity you execute the code you have there?

Comment: @BasvanStein  currently I finish the mainlaunch activity and start my splash activity and in the splashactiviy i start again the mainlaunch activity..

Answer (score 0):

We can do it for example by interface:

```
  // our app class
  public class MyApplication extends Application implements IComplete {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        // rest code.. but I dont want it is excuded until my splashactivity

    }

    @Override
    public void notify(boolean result) {
         // do the rest code part here ...
    }
}

// the interface
public interface IComplete {
    void notify(boolean result);
}

// and the interface calling code snipped in the SplashActivity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    ((MyApplication)getApplication()).notify(true);
}
```

hope helps you,

Good luck )

Comment: thank you for your reply but its not what I want. Because the my class is already set as MainLauncher and OnCreate method of the class is triggered somehow automatically in application class. I just want to wait until the splashscreen is closed. But problem is, after startActivity, my mainlauncher also is called.. but if I can keep the execution in the startActivity it could be good.